Visual Studio 2022 & ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : illegal characters in path
I'm working on a very complex live website, I've been modifying a bit of the code as I see needed for improvements, adding new pages, modifying controllers, etc.
I am continually checking changes on the localhost and, when it does what I want it to, publishing it online. Over the last couple of weeks, every now and then, it suddenly refuses to build throwing an error

Illegal characters in path

in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.StaticWebAssets.JSModules.targets.
I can see no good reason for this, it means that I then need to go back to the last working version, copy all my newer changes to it, and then build it again. This is a real chore but always solves the problem, which suggests to me that the errors are being generated by Visual Studio and are not anything that I have done.
I've done all the standard things like deleting the bin and obj folders and .vs. I've even copied the solution to a different location just in case it is to do with its folder name.
Is there any way of find out where the issue lies?

attach the debugger of another instance of visual studio to the one emitting the error. then use the auto/locals/watch features to figure out which path offends it, and track back to the root cause

Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not sure how to do this.  I've looked this up but there seem to loads of suggestions but nothing which makes much sense to me.  I only want to find out what is causing this when to run on my local server.  More detail on how to go about this would be appreciated.

I found the offending file name, a user had uploaded an image containing %, so I now trap this in the upload file code in the controller and tell the user to lose % signs.  % seems to cause problems in various area connected with HTML pages and, its seems, Visual Studio, although Windows allows it to be used in file names.

cool. in windows, % is the delimiter for environment variables in paths.
